# Elastic search + Heartbeat - Is it possible to check if java app is running?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, grafana, heartbeat

Is it possible to check if java application (standard "main function" app, not web app) is running with Heartbeat (https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/heartbeat) ?

Comment: Heartbeat can ping a host:port in order to assess that a component/application is running. Does your Java app listen on a TCP port?

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't. Instead you can use the FileBeat system module which will monitor your OS layer, info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-system.html)